# Monoid homomorphism without defined operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let $\mathbf{M_1}=(M_1,\star,e)$ and $\mathbf{M_2}=(M_2, \square, \epsilon)$ are two monoides. If $h: \mathbf{M_1} \rightarrow \mathbf{M_1} \times \mathbf{M_2}$ and $h(a)=(a,\epsilon)$ prove:

a) $h$ is homomorphism and $\text{1-1}$ of monoid $\mathbf{M_1}$ to $\mathbf{M_1} \times \mathbf{M_2}$

b) $h$ with inherited operations follows $h(\mathbf{M_1}) \cong \mathbf{M_1}$.

I have the problem. I do not know how to show homomorphism between two monoides because there is no definition of operation $\star$ and $\square$, and that problem was on my exam yesterday. I know for homomorphism must be $h(a \star b) = \ ? \ = h(a) \ \square \ h(b)$. I appreciate your help.

Comment: First, $\mathbf M_1 \times \mathbf M_2$ denotes the monoid $(M_1 \times M_2, *, (e, \epsilon))$, where $(x_1,x_2) * (y_1,y_2)$ is defined to be $(x_1 \star y_1,x_2 \,\square\, y_2)$ for all $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$ in $M_1 \times M_2$. So, $h$ is a homomorphism if $h(a \star b) = h(a) * h(b)$ for every $a$ and $b$ in $M_1$.

Comment: I understand your point. Thank you!